# binding an event with dynamically created tag

Tags: javascript, events, onclicklistener

Suppose I have a dynamic tag injected at the end of the loading page, using some jquery plugin. Say this tag has a class '.myclass' I want to bind an event so I tried :

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.myclass', function(){console.log('yes');});
```

The problem is that, no function is triggered, even when I run this code on my console so it seems that all the related events are listened elsewhere. How can I make this code run correctly ?

Comment: I don't believe `toggle` is an event-name (certainly not in native JavaScript), so is there something on the page firing that event: `$(selector).trigger('toggle')`? Or are you trying to bind to a jQuery method-name?

Comment: @DavidThomas even if I use the 'click' event with one single function to trigger, I have the same problem

Comment: Can you show your code in a live demo, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar?

Comment: it would be hard for me because I am new to this project I am working on, and it seems to be full with plugins, that seems to interfer...

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: @bfavaretto no error is output

Comment: @DavidThomas if I run in my console something as simple as $(document).on( 'click', '.myclass', function(){console.log('yes');}); nothing happens

Comment: I didn't know you could pass multiple handlers to `.on` like that. Can you really? I believe the first function is being passed as the `data` parameter, see http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @bfavaretto I am going to check it, but see my edit, even if I run something like $(document).on( 'click', '.myclass', function(){console.log('yes');}); it doesn't triggers anything

Comment: @bfavaretto to test, I added a tag that covered tha `.myclass` one, and then I tried to bind events with this test tag, and no event is fired. I don't really understand what's going no, it looks like some `prevent default` thing, but I don't find this in the code...

Answer (score 0):

Find where the problem was coming from. It was related to the [jquery plugin icheck](https://github.com/damirfoy/iCheck/blob/master/jquery.icheck.min.js), which customize all the eventlisteners (example, $('document').on('change', target,...) becomes $('document').on('Ifchanged', target,...)), so this plugin captures all the events related to checkbox.